# Fancybox v3 beta - Doesn't seem to be suport SSL

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, fancybox

I am using Fancybox v3 beta.

I am using the `data-fancybox-href` attribute to set the url in which fancybox gets the content via ajax.

The problem that I am having is that in an SSL enabled page(https), it doesn't seem to work.

I get this error message

`The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.`

I tried doing variations to my `data-fancybox-href` url

```
foo/bar/
/foo/bar/
//foo/bar/
https://domain.com/foo/bar/
```

But none of them worked.

Does Fancybox v3 support SSL?

Comment: `Does Fancybox v3 support SSL?` ...hmmm, does v2.x do? are the calling page and the ajaxed page from the same domain? have you tried the option `ajax : {headers  : { 'X-fancyBox': true }}`. I don't think beta versions get that much support.

Comment: I don't know if v2 supports it. The calling page and ajaxed page are in the same domain. I tried adding the option you suggested but unfortunately, it did nothing to solve the problem.